# Issue With option Tag In HTML While Storing in Database By PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-select

I want to save `value` as `Hsn/product code` and option text as `product`.

i defined value for `hsn` because  i want to show it on my `active webpage` as `Selected option Hsn code`.

but problem is that when i submit form, then i recieve same value in `productName` & `ProductHSN` in our Database

And i want to store `productName` as `saree, lehga, etc`
And `ProductHSN` as `W1, M1,etc` .

plase help

```
<select class="form-control" id="colTwo2" name="colTwo[]" data- 
type="productName" required="">
<option value=""> --SELECT-- </option>
<option value="W1">Saree</option>
<option value="W2">Lehga</option>
<option value="G1">Kurti</option>
<option value="G2">Salwar Suit</option>
<option value="G3">Lagi</option>
<option value="G4">Hairam</option>
<option value="G5">Long Suit</option>
<option value="W3">Goun</option>
<option value="W10">Chunri</option>
<option value="M1">Suiting</option>
<option value="M2">Shirting</option>
<option value="G6">Jeans</option>
<option value="M4">T-Shirt</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The option text is not sent when you submit a form. only the value is sent. You should not need the text anyway - the value already uniquely identifies what was selected.

Comment: (And if you have a list of the possible option texts and their values stored in your database, which is what people normally do, then you can easily retrieve the text associated with any given value when you need to display it).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting same value because the value in option value="" is only sent. Not the option text.

You could use PHP explode function.

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id="product" name="product" required>
<option value=""> --SELECT-- </option>
<option value="W1|Saree">Saree</option>
<option value="W2|Lehga">Lehga</option>
<option value="G1|Kurti">Kurti</option>
<option value="G2|Salwar Suit">Salwar Suit</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
   <?php
        $result = $_POST['product'];
        $result_explode = explode('|', $result);
        $producthsn =  $result_explode[0];
        $productname = $result_explode[1];
   ?>
```

In the select box we are giving 2 options with a '|' separator to split the values. In action page result is exploded into an array. You can then insert each one separately in the database.

Comment: but i want to show hsn code in another input box using this option value, then it would show hsn as well as product also